# Show Author name in single.php (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I need to display the Author of the post in the single.php file in Wordpress. The reference indicates that the_author(); only works within the loop.

I've been looking for others forums and nothing found.

Any idea?

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
    <div class="bar_info">
         <?php echo "By: ".the_author(); ?>
         <?php
                foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
                    echo category->cat_name.', ';
                }
         ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't get it. you still leverage the loop in `single.php`, so you can still use `the_author();` or `get_the_author();`, etch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `single.php`, you most likely have a call to `the_post()`. You'll find **WordPress** [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) will work just fine after this line. In other words, you can use `the_author` in `single.php`.

**Edit:** Based on the code you've updated in your question, you'll need to put something like the following at the top of `single.php`:

`<?php if( have_posts() ) the_post(); ?>`

Also, if you want to use the author name in an `echo` statement, use `get_the_author` instead. `the_author` actually echos it for you already.

Comment: I have the code edited in the main question and the_author do not work in single.php but in php files where there is a loop, yes.

Answer (score 3):

As long as there is a $post object, you are technically "in the loop" — even if only one post exists in the query object, which is the case in single.php.  As long as you've executed the_post(); template tags are accessible, so **the_author();** will work just fine.  If you want to point to author archives **the_author_posts_link();** will output a link to the appropriate archive as well as the author name in the anchor text.

UPDATE:

Also your code is wrong.  the_author echos the author name,  get_the_author() would treat it as a variable.  This would work:

```
    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <div class="bar_info">
         By: <?php the_author(); ?>
         <?php
                foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
                    echo category->cat_name.', ';
                }
         ?>
    </div>
```

Alternatively this would also work:

```
     <?php the_post(); ?>      
     <div class="bar_info">
         echo "By: " . get_the_author();
                foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
                    echo category->cat_name.', ';
                }
         ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use **the_author** in you single.php inside post loop.
- you can use **echo get_the_author**  instead of the_author.
- You can use **the_author_posts_link** if you need author name with archive link.

Answer (score 0):

**Do like this anywhere inside php tag**

```
$post_id =  get_the_ID();
$author_id = get_post_field('post_author', $post_id);

$author_id = get_post_field('post_author', get_the_ID());

$author = trim(get_the_author_meta('first_name', $author_id) . ' ' . get_the_author_meta('last_name', $author_id));
```

You will get the author name inside the `$author` variable

You Can show this now using echo like this

`<h2><?php echo $author; ?></h2>`