# How to display author name on my website post pages?

Tags: css, wordpress, web

How to display author name near the date on  my website homepage and single post page? . Is there is css code for that.  Iam using hemingway theme. And my website is   www.avjtrickz.com .    please help me,  Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use:

```
 <?php $author = get_the_author(); ?>
```

or:

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

Here you can find more information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author

And here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author

And here: [Show Author name in single.php (Wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797863/show-author-name-in-single-php-wordpress)

Comment: That's great. I would be grateful if you mark this answer as a proper solving of your problem.

Comment: Done!!  I have one more issue. My website homepage showing a warning error message as (  Warning: Missing argument 2 for hemingway_custom_more_link() in/home/kiranjithz/public_html/wp-content/themes/hemingway/functions.phpon line 179  )   How to fix It.please help

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done using the WordPress codex for author. This reference needs to be used in the Loop. There is no CSS for this.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?>
```

reference : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/